# Given $H_{N}=\{\vec{x} \in [-1,1]^N:\sum_{i=1}^N x_i = 0\}$, what is the smallest subset $S \subset H_{2N}$ such that $\mathrm{conv}(S)=H_{2N}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

### Motivation:

This is [related to a different question I asked in April](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328558/understanding-the-geometry-of-h-n-vecx-in-n-nn-sum-i-1n-x-i-0). It occurred to me while thinking about the sums of uniform random variables and it stuck in my mind because it's the special case of a more general problem:

> Given the hyperplane cut of $[-1,1]^N$,$H_{N}=\{\vec{x} \in [-1,1]^N:\sum_{i=1}^N x_i = 0\}$, what is the vertex set of $H_N$?

which reduces to the original question when $N \in 2\mathbb{N}$.

### My conjecture for this problem:

I conjecture that:

\begin{equation}
V_{2N}=\{\vec{x} \in \{-1,+1\}^{2N}:\sum_{i=1}^{2N} x_i = 0\} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

is the smallest set such that $\mathrm{conv}(V_{2N})=H_{2N}$ where we note that:

\begin{equation}
\lvert V_{2N} \rvert= {2N \choose N} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

and it's relatively easy to show that:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{conv}(V_{2N}) \subset H_{2N} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

So far I haven't managed to show that $\mathrm{conv}(V_{2N}) = H_{2N}$ but I have managed to show that if we define:

\begin{equation}
\forall k < N, V_{2k}=\{\vec{x} \in H_{2N}:\sum_{i \in \Gamma} x_i = \sum_{j \notin \Gamma} \lvert x_j \rvert = 0 \land \{x_i\}_{i \in \Gamma} \in \{-1,+1\}^{2k} \} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

then we have:

\begin{equation}
\forall k < N-1, \mathrm{conv}(V_{2k}) \subset \mathrm{conv}(V_{2k+2}) \tag{5}
\end{equation}

I have spent some time thinking about this problem and at this point I'm not sure how to proceed. The challenge is basically to show that $V_{2N}$ is the vertex set of $H_{2N}$.

Comment: You should consider the [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) as, if $C$ is a convex body and $x\in EP(C)$ (its extreme points) $C\setminus \{x\}$ is convex, therefore $EP(C)\subset S$.

Comment: Insight : It seems to me that, if $C$ is intersection of closed half-spaces and bounded, then $S=EP(C)$, but I didn't check this formally.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Thank you for sharing these insights. I suspect that your last point is true and I'm currently thinking about a proof.

Comment: Good Luck ! Do not hesitate to interact anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to verify (see the comment by  Duchamp Gérard H. E. and (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point)) that the set $V_{2N}$ is precisely the set of extreme points  ${\bf EP}(H_{2N})$ of $H_{2N}$. Clearly 
$V_{2N} \subset {\bf EP}(H_{2N})$. To see the converse, suppose $x \in {\bf EP}(H_{2N})$.
Let $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^{2N}$ denote the standard basis vectors in ${\bf R}^{2N}$. If there were two coordinates $1 \le i<j \le 2N$   such that $|x_i|<1$ and $|x_j| <1$, then the representation
$$x=\frac{(x+\delta (e_i-e_j))+(x-\delta (e_i-e_j))}{2}$$
for small enough $\delta$, would show that $x$ is not an extreme point of $H_{2N}$.
If precisely one index $i \le 2N$ satisfies $|x_i|<1$, then the sum 
$\sum_{j \le 2N \,: \, j \ne i}x_j$ is $\pm 1$, so $x$  could not be in $H_{2N}$.
The only remaining possibility is that $x \in V_{2N}.$